# Libgdx - How to pass a variable value from one screen to another?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a game for Android phones and I need a player number from screen where I select it to another screen where I use it for something else. On screen where I select specific number, method for returning number of players works perfectly but when I use that method on another screen it returns zero. I select number (picture for specific number) from ScrollPane. When I change screen I clear screen and draw new one as usual. So my question is how can I save that value and return it even when screen has changed?

Comment: Can you explain how you are changing screens? I dont understand if you want to pass a variable to another screen just past it trough the other screen constructor? `game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(var));`

Comment: Thank you very much. I was so focused on using Preferences for that so I forgot about this simple thing :) write your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it through the constructor of the other screen

```
game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(var));
```