# How can I use variables through different classes?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

in the class GameScreen I wrote this code for a score:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()&& executed==true) {
  MyGdxGame.camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
  for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    if (sprite[zahl[i]].getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y) && zahl[4] == zahl[i]) {
      int scoreValue = Integer.parseInt(score);
      scoreValue++;
      score = String.valueOf(scoreValue);
      executed= false;
    }
    if (sprite[zahl[i]].getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y) && zahl[4] != zahl[i]){
      this.dispose();
      game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game));
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

The second `if` refers to the class `GameOverScreen`. So if a user loses the game, the `GameOverScreen` would be shown. Now I want to show the reached score on the `GameOverScreen`. Therefore I have to use the changing variable `score` from the `GameScreen` class in the `GameOverScreen` class.

**My question is: How can I use variables through different classes?**

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, not a broad 'how do I do this?'. I'd strongly suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your question to take account of the suggestions there.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope I can now take account of the suggestions.

Comment: Simply the question is: How to pass variables from one screen to another.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176696/libgdx-how-to-pass-a-variable-value-from-one-screen-to-another

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can save the variable on Android sharedpreferences. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: Thank you! That´s what I was looking for.

Comment: this will solve your issue, But its not a professional way. Go with Kuffs 's answer. Using sharedpreference will cause extra memory and file read/write time.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a constructor that takes the score as the parameter in your GameOverScreen.

e.g:

```
game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, TheScore));
```